# Inno Setup Download plugin not able to download file due to TLS 1.1/1.2 issue

Tags: ssl, inno-setup, tls1.2, inno-download-plugin

While i'm trying to download the file from Inno Setup download plugin, it fails with following error:

[image]

When explored more on this error I identified that enabling TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 from Internet Explorer settings it worked fine. But when I run the code in Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 (where it supports only TLS 1.0 so I cannot enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2) it fails.

Code:

```pascal
idpAddFile('https://www.testwebsite.com/downloads/SetupFiles.zip',  
           ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SetupFiles.zip'));
idpDownloadAfter(wpSelectDir);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.1/1.2 is indeed not supported on Windows XP. Inno Download Plugin (IDP) is just a thin wrapper around Windows built-in implementation of HTTP. So no change in IDP code will allow TLS 1.2. You would have to implement HTTP and TLS from the scratch, what is an insane task.

Though note that the the problem about TLS *version*, not is not about *certificate*.

The only reasonable solution that supports Windows XP is enabling TLS 1.0 on the server.